# jQuery difference between two dates returns Nan

Tags: jquery, date

I have two dates. One from datepicker and the other is today's date. I want to get difference between these two dates using jQuery but It prompts Nan. Here is my code

```
var mydob = jQuery('#datepicker').val();
  alert(mydob);// This prompts value from date picker accurately
                var newdate = '<?php echo date('m/d/Y') ?>';
        alert(newdate); // This prompts accurate today's date
        var diffx = Math.abs(newdate-mydob);
                var diffz = diffx/(24*60*60*1000);
                alert(diffx); This prompts Nan
                if(diffz < 5110)///if it is less than 14
                {
                    alert('under 14');
                    return false;
                }
```

Comment: because you are subtracting 2 strings...

Comment: Show some effort on your part maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is both `mydob` and `newdate` are strings, not numerical values.

```
var mydob = jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
alert(mydob); // This prompts value from date picker accurately
var newdate = $.datepicker.parseDate( 'm/d/yy', '<?php echo date('m/d/Y') ?>');
alert(newdate); // This prompts accurate today's date
var diffx = Math.abs(newdate.getTime() - mydob.getTime());
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fG6NN/)

Comment: diffx is returning some value. Is this value is in seconds?

Comment: then how can I find if the returning value is less than 14 years. thanks

Comment: I think if you want to allow the users to select a date older then 14 years then use the option `maxDate: '-14y'` like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fG6NN/2/ so that use will not get an option to enter a greater value

Comment: not getting the required results. I just want if the user is under 18 then it should prompt 'under 18' and return false...

Answer (score 0):

Your 'newdate' is  set from a PHP echo, which is a string of a formatted date (formatted as m/d/Y). You need to set newdate to a Date object. I'm a bit confused, as most people are when inlining one scripting language inside another, as to if you need to get the date from the server-side for some reason. If you can get it from the client, then just 'var newdate = new Date()' is fine, otherwise:

```
var newdate = new Date("<?= date('m/d/Y') ?>");
```

I'm not 100% sure what the .val() on your #datepicker will return as I don't know what's generating it, but that may be a string too, so you'll need to initialize a Date() object from that too.

Comment: date stored in both variables is in format of m/d/y. your code is returning string. So not getting the required results. I just want if the user is under 18 then it should prompt 'under 18' and return false.